# Installing Munin on debian 6 and getting 403

Tags: apache, munin

I've installed Munin on my server but when I try to access the mypage.com/munin i get 403 error: Forbidden, You don't have permission to access /munin/ on this server.

My configuration is the following:

- The node and the master are installed in the same server.
- The file /etc/munin/apache.conf has the following configuration

  ```
   Alias /munin /var/cache/munin/www
   <Directory /var/cache/munin/www>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Options FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      <IfModule mod_expires.c>
         ExpiresActive On
         ExpiresDefault M310
      </IfModule>
  </Directory>
  ```
- The munin conf is /etc/munin/munin.conf

  ```
  dbdir   /var/lib/munin
  htmldir /var/cache/munin/www
  logdir /var/log/munin
  rundir  /var/run/munin
  ....
  [myserver]
      address 127.0.0.1
      use_node_name yes
  ```
- while the node configuration (/etc/munin/munin-node.conf) is the default one.

In the folder /var/cache/munin/www the graphs are not being generated because this folder is empty, but also the logs are not generated and I dont understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Use the new version of Munin 2.0 !

Create and edit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list and add:

```
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main
```

Update the repositories and then install munin

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install munin -t squeeze-backports
```

This version of Munin defaults to using CGI to generate HTMLs and GRAPHs. So be sure to do this before configuring a virtual host:

```
# apt-get install libapache2-mod-fcgid
# a2enmod fcgid
```

Configure your virtual host:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/cache/munin/www
        ServerName munin.example.com
        Alias /static /etc/munin/static
        # Rewrites
        RewriteEngine On
        # HTML
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .html$ [or]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)           /usr/lib/munin/cgi/munin-cgi-html/$1 [L]
        # Images
        # - remove path to munin-cgi-graph, if present
        RewriteRule ^/munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph/(.*) /$1
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}                 !^/static
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}                 .png$
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)  /usr/lib/munin/cgi/munin-cgi-graph/$1 [L]
        # Ensure we can run (fast)cgi scripts
        ScriptAlias /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph /usr/lib/munin/cgi/munin-cgi-graph
        <Location /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph>
                Options +ExecCGI
                <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                        SetHandler fcgid-script
                </IfModule>
                <IfModule !mod_fcgid.c>
                        SetHandler cgi-script
                </IfModule>
                Allow from all
        </Location>
        ScriptAlias /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-html /usr/lib/munin/cgi/munin-cgi-html
        <Location /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-html>
                Options +ExecCGI
                <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                        SetHandler fcgid-script
                </IfModule>
                <IfModule !mod_fcgid.c>
                        SetHandler cgi-script
                </IfModule>
                Allow from all
        </Location>
        <Location />
                Options +ExecCGI
                <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                        SetHandler fcgid-script
                </IfModule>
                <IfModule !mod_fcgid.c>
                        SetHandler cgi-script
                </IfModule>
                Allow from all
        </Location>
        <Location /static/>
                SetHandler None
                Allow from all
        </Location>
        <Directory /var/cache/munin/www>
                Order allow,deny
                #Allow from localhost 127.0.0.0/8 ::1
                Allow from all
                Options None
                # Set the default expiration time for files to 5 minutes 10 seconds from
                # their creation (modification) time.  There are probably new files by
                # that time.
                #
            <IfModule mod_expires.c>
                ExpiresActive On
                ExpiresDefault M310
            </IfModule>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And finally, start to enjoy the new version of Munin

```
# a2ensite munin
# /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Now you can access to munin in http://munin.example.com after a few minutes. Let munin collect some data first.

Comment: I've used this vhost config on Ubuntu 16.04 to get fast-cgi working, but it is overly complex.. Also the official docs mention munin-httpd, but this http daemon doesn't seem to be present on the version (2.0.25) available in 16.04. I would prefer to use a http daemon provided by munin over this insane config..